# php string explode for binary code

Tags: php, string, binary

I'm on search for a php snipped to cut following binary code:

`$code = "10011";`

I need from `$code` an explode array like `$codes = array(100,1,1);` for example:

`echo $codes[0]; // echo result: 100`

I'm not sure what php function is helpful, thank you very much for help!

Comment: In other words, you want to split the string before each 1?

Comment: yes, that's right: 1000100101 = 1000, 100, 10, 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a regex, *a 1 with zero or more 0*:

```
preg_match_all('~10*~', $str, $m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

If your string eventually starts with one or more zeros, you can change it to:

```
preg_match_all('~10*|0+~', $str, $m);
```

Comment: wow! that's smart solution. thank you very much, you made my day :)

Comment: and if I need 1000101 = 1000000, 100, 1 one more example:
101001100 = 100000000, 1000000, 1000, 100

Comment: @Korty: in  this case the approach is totally different. You have to convert the string to a binary number and test each power of 2 (each bit) using [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Comment: I could understand your original question, but what's the point of this new request?

Comment: @Korty: something like [this](https://3v4l.org/K9KC5) or [this](https://3v4l.org/qaH8J) but I'm sure there's a better way to do that.

Comment: I get a request like $num = 19; this number is in binary 10011. I have a array like $arr = array(10000 => 'A', 1000 => 'B', 100=>'C', 10=>'D', 1=>'E'); In best case I get after decbin($num) an array('A','D','C');

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: exactly this is the solution

Comment: @Korty: refresh the page, I edited the comment. Better, [this one](https://3v4l.org/lUdCK)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: your last code solves the request. But I don't understand why I can't change echo into $arr[]= (to fill an array)

Comment: @Korty: I'm sure you will find how to do it.